# localhost:8000 failed to load

Tags: php, google-chrome, laravel-5

I cannot load the webpage of my laravel when I try to put in my URL `localhost:8000`. It gives me the following error :

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
>
> GET http://localhost:8000/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONS

The last time I used laravel, it worked fine but now when I load it to browser, it doesn't work anymore. Screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

**you need to remove chrome extensions and then try again and see if it works.**

Answer (score 0):

Try the command, `php -S 0.0.0.0:80 -t ~`. Make sure you are Superuser, so if you're on UNIX, type `sudo` before the command. `php -S` runs a server on `0.0.0.0:80`. `0.0.0.0` means to run the server on `localhost` on all interfaces on port `80`. Port `80` is the default web port that is accessed by web browsers. `-t ~` means to use the directory `~` for hosting. You could actually replace `~` with any directory with an `index.php` in it.